# A formula for finding the increment of the radial volume and the distance r from the center of the disc

Tags: fluid-mechanics

The system consists of two disks. The upper disc is connected to the pipe. The disk below is a plane.
The gas flows out radially from the disc gap. A formula for finding the increment of the radial volume and the distance r from the center of the disc.

I mean that the greater the distance r from the center of the disc, the larger the volume of the gap with r as the radius.  From the center, what is the formula for the increase in the radial volume of the gap and r?

Suppose the flow of gas flowing from the pipeline is $Q$, the radius of the pipeline is $R$, and the height of the gap is $h$, $h << R$.  It is assumed that the gas is an ideal gas with no viscosity and no temperature change.

The calculation method I think of is as follows:

$\lim_{\Delta r\to 0}{\cfrac{(r+\Delta r)^2πh-r^2πh}{\Delta r}}=2rπh$

correct?

[image]

---

When h is constant, $V$ is a function of $r$.  When $r$ has an increment $\Delta r$, $V$ also has an increment $\Delta V$ . I want to know the relationship between $\Delta V$  and $\Delta r$.

Comment: This looks like homework, good luck.

Comment: @SolarMike Not homework, this is the question I want to understand.  Can you answer

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far. Hint: apply mass continuity.

Comment: @enbin zheng please edit you post accordingly and incorporate your calculations in your original question.

Comment: @idkfa I added my thinking to the question.

Comment: Why do you consider r->0? Shouldn't you find an expression depending on A? Please show your complete calculations and explain where you have trouble. SE is a Q&A site, there are other sites where you solve problems step by step together.

Comment: @idkfa What other websites can ask similar questions?

Comment: Probably any physics forums will do. I don't want to extend this discussion in the comments any further as I feel we're already going over the limit, however I can't really understand what prevents you from putting in the work and just do the calculations from start to end. We can then look over it and answer a specific question, regarding a concept or point out a mistake. At some point you need to calculate it anyway. In my experience the quality of your answers depends on the quality of the question.

Comment: @idkfa In the question I have added my calculation formula, which describes the increase in volume as r increases.  Is my formula correct?

Comment: @idkfa I modified the question, maybe this is better?

Comment: @SolarMike When h is constant, $V$ is a function of $r$.  When $r$ has an increment $\Delta r$, $V$ also has an increment $\Delta V$ . I want to know the relationship between $\Delta r$ and $\Delta V$.

Answer (score 2):

Since area between the plates is $A=\pi \cdot r^2$ and volume is $V=A \cdot h$ then $V=\pi \cdot r^2 \cdot h$. Am I missing something you are trying to do?

Comment: I mean that the greater the distance r from the center of the disc, the larger the volume of the gap with r as the radius.  From the center, what is the formula for the increase in the radial volume of the gap and r?

Comment: daveM2 answered your question. The Volume $V$ is a function of $r$ and $h$, exactly like you asked. I personally suspect though, this is not what is asked in your assignment. I guess I'm not alone with this since @Solar Mike suggested mass continuity.

Comment: @idkfa When h is constant, $V$ is a function of $r$.  When $r$ has an increment $\Delta r$, $V$ also has an increment $\Delta V$ . I want to know the relationship between $\Delta r$ and $\Delta V$.

Comment: Now I got you. Yes, then you're calculation in your question is correct. You can answer the question yourself and accept the answer. You could have also just calculated the derivative with respect to r for V. dV/dr if you're familiar with that concept.

Comment: @idkfa $\lim_{\Delta r\to 0}{\cfrac{(r+\Delta r)^2πh-r^2πh}{\Delta r}}=2rπh$  correct?